# php if statement doesn't work with jquery variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, if-statement

The jQuery variable I send to my PHP doesn't work (Or atleast, it doesn't seem to work ). I've sent it to my php with ajax.

Please take a look at it, perhaps you can see the problem:

```
                $('.do').click(function(){
                var cid2 = $(this).attr('id');
                var gebridauthpos = cid2.indexOf('||');
                var gebridauth = cid2.substring(gebridauthpos+2);
                $.post("agenda.php", {gebridauth: gebridauth});
                alert(gebridauth);
                <?php
                    if ($admin == true || isset($_POST['gebridauth']) AND $_SESSION['id'] == $_POST['gebridauth']) {
                        echo "$('#dialog').dialog('open');\n";
                        echo "var cid = $(this).attr('id');\n";
                        echo "var datum = cid.substr(0, 10);\n";
                        echo "var naampos = cid.indexOf('|');\n";
                        echo "var gebridpos = cid.indexOf('||');\n";
                        echo "var naam = cid.substring(naampos+1,gebridpos);\n";
                        echo "var gebrid = cid.substring(gebridpos+2);\n";
                        echo "$.ajax({\n";
                            echo "type: \"POST\",\n";
                            echo "url: \"agenda.php\",\n";
                            echo "data: naam,\n";
                            echo "success: function(){\n";
                                echo "$('#gebruikerinput').html(\"<input type='text' READONLY='' size='35' value='\" + naam +\"'>\");\n";
                                echo "$('#gebridinput').html(\"<input type='hidden' name='gebridtextbox' value='\" + gebrid + \"'>\");\n";
                                echo "$('#datuminput').html(\"<input type='text' READONLY='' size='12' name='datum' value='\" + datum + \"'>\");\n";
                            echo "}\n";
                        echo "})\n";
                        echo "return false;\n";
                    }
                ?>
            });
```

Basically what I want to do, is using "gebridauth" in the if statement of my PHP when I click on a TD. If the TD is the same as the person that's logged in, show the dialog.

Comment: Echoing every single line of JS *and* escaped quotes? Reading this hurts.

Comment: Agenda.php is the current PHP the code is in. It basically generates a table with data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback on your `$.post` call, right now you're just sending off the POST and not paying any attention to the what the server sends back so no dialog will appear. I think you want something more like this (with real code where the big comment is):

```
$.post("agenda.php", {gebridauth: gebridauth}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // If the server sent back a "show the dialog" value in data then
    // show the dialog and all the other stuff that's currently in a
    // bunch of PHP echo calls.
});
```

Comment: Sounds interesting... But doesn't that mean I can't check on $admin == true and $_session['id'] == $_POST['gebridauth'] ?

Comment: @Yihka: You check that stuff on the server and then send some information back to the client as the POST response. Then the client looks at the POST response in the success callback and shows the dialog and whatever else it needs to do.

Comment: I see... Currently agenda.php is the same file where the code is in, I thought it would be possible to use the $_POST that way, since it stays in the same file.

Comment: @Yihka: That is just an u fortunate side effect off the PHP programming model, both parts are in the same place when you look at it but they are executed in different places. This stuff is not as hard as it looksq thought, you just have to get used to how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how AJAX works. You can't mix Javascript and PHP like that, since they're running at completely different times on different systems. If you're POSTing to `agenda.php`, your PHP code needs to be in the file `agenda.php`. That file should *not* contain Javascript. You also won't be able to `echo` Javascript in return like that.

Comment: So far, the code seems to work quite good, apart from the $_POST. agenda.php is the file same file where all the code is in. I thought it was possible to return a POST and use the code right at the same time with AJAX. But if that isn't possible, it is going to be harder than I thought it would be.

Comment: Well yes, it works, apart from the part that doesn't. ;-P You need to understand what's executing in which order. PHP runs on the server, Javascript on the client. I'm kind of at a loss how to explain this fundamental difference, as this could fill a whole book on its own. Maybe you should go back to basics and revisit an AJAX tutorial or book.